# backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged not working?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am having a trouble with background worker

```
private void backgroundPBar_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
```

The function doesn't execute when **backgroundPBar.ReportProgress(value);**

here's the code:

```
private void backgroundPBar_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    while (fileTransfer.busy) {
        if (fileTransfer.sum > 0) {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32((fileTransfer.sum * 100) / fileTransfer.fileSize);
            backgroundPBar.ReportProgress(value);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundPBar_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    progressBarFile.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial of how to use backgroundworker with [ProgressBar](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar)

You should call **(RunWorkerAsync)** first then the backgroundPBar_DoWork will start executing its code.

```
backgroundPBar.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the progress event wired up:

```
backgroundPBar.ProgressChanged += backgroundPBar_ProgressChanged
```

From you description, it seems like it isn't.  The assumption here is that `fileTransfer.busy` is true and `fileTransfer.sum > 0` is also true.

Also, make sure you have your the properties of the background worker set:

```
backgroundPBar.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

(as I see "The Mask" mentioned").

Comment: yea.. im sure of all about you said .. i see the value changes in the console.. as u see Console.WriteLine(value);
and about backgroundPBar.ProgressChanged += backgroundPBar_ProgressChanged // the form should created .. i checked and i see this.backgroundPBar.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.backgroundPBar_ProgressChanged);

Comment: @MurHafSoz How are you calling the `DoWork()`.  You didn't post that code, but something doesn't look right with what the fileTransfer object is doing.  How is fileTransfer getting initiated?

Comment: the file transfer works perfectly .. i used to have everything done and the progress also worked.. my problem was the form was lagging because something wrong with the threads so i changed the plan to use backgroundWorker and here i'm .. i call RunWorkerAsync .. when i start the ProgressForm .. so its working because i can see the value in the Console

Comment: when i send large file console shows me .. the value like 
0000000 1111111 2222222 because the (sent*100)/size ... i mean if it goes for alot of zero 00000000000 does that have anything with my problem... !! note when it goes to 1 or 2 or 6 the progress doesnt move at all

Comment: @MurHafSoz What does `this.Text` say? since you have that firing in the change event, too.

Comment: nothing .. i tried also messageBox.show .. it didn't came out
but i've figured out .. when i call reportProgress from the SENDFILE method it self.. it fires it and it changes the progressBar.. but then the connection Closes Immediately.. and the sendfile doesnt complete .. so i changed the plan .. now im using another way it seems ti work good without backgroundworker

Comment: @MurHafSoz It still seems wrong.  The fileTransfer object (whatever that is) should be initializing in the `DoWork()` routine, but your routine is just checking if it's busy or not.    Since it isn't, your fileTransfer is still just happening on the main thread.

Comment: that because my filetransfer object was initialized in its own class it is not included in (progressFORM) .. i've fixed it
thanks alot for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

don't forget that to use `ReportProgress()` method you must set [`WorkerReportsProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)  as `true`.

Comment: sure i've already changed that to true.. it would gives me an exception if i didn't

Answer (score 0):

I've been having problems getting the ProgressChanged event to fire immediately when the ReportProgress method is called.  Because they are seperate threads, I had to resort to thread synchronization.  I used a couple WaitHandles and the SignalAndWait method to synchronize the two threads.  I kinda defeats the purpose of the background worker, but if I really want the UI thread to do something on time, it really has to make the background worker wait until the UI thread got the message and performed the work.

```
    Private ReportProgressWaitEvent As New AutoResetEvent(False)
    Private ReportProgressReadyWaitEvent As New ManualResetEvent(False)
    Private Sub ReportProgress(backgroundWorkerProgressEvents As BackgroundWorkerProgressEventsEnum, userState As Object)
        ReportProgressReadyWaitEvent.Reset()
        _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(backgroundWorkerProgressEvents, userState)
        WaitHandle.SignalAndWait(ReportProgressReadyWaitEvent, ReportProgressWaitEvent)
    End Sub
    Private Sub _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged
        ... do work ...
        ReportProgressReadyWaitEvent.WaitOne()
        ReportProgressWaitEvent.Set()
    End Sub
```